# postgres avoiding extra quotes inside a string

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have following select query which I will be passing to the database to get results back,

```
sql = "select * from movies where title = #{movie_title};"
```

`movie_title` contains a value that can sometimes contain single quotes and other chars that need escaping. I have come across dollar quoted string which is working well when used inside a `INSERT` statement but `SELECT` is not behaving the same, if I use `$$#{movie_title}$$` like this it just doesn't get converted to a value inside `movie_title`. Is there any solution for this?

I am using postgres 9.5.0 and I am programming using ruby.

Comment: Use the Ruby's Postgresql driver to pass the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Bad idea. Don't do that, as you are making your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and also making your life harder. Read more about prepared SQL statements, SQL injection etc.

In short, unless you are using some ORM, you should do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'pg'

if ARGV.length != 1 then
    puts "Usage: prepared_statement.rb rowId"
    exit
end

rowId = ARGV[0]

begin

    con = PG.connect :dbname => 'testdb', :user => 'janbodnar'

    con.prepare 'stm1', "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE Id=$1"
    rs = con.exec_prepared 'stm1', [rowId]

    puts rs.values 

rescue PG::Error => e

    puts e.message 

ensure

    rs.clear if rs
    con.close if con

end
```

(an example taken from http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlruby/)

Edit: You don't need to use prepared statements, you can also use your DB lib's methods which provide proper parameter binding:

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG::Connection.open(:dbname => 'test')
res = conn.exec_params('SELECT $1 AS a, $2 AS b, $3 AS c', [1, 2, nil])
```

Take a look at docs for [`PG#exec_params`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection:exec_params)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial, it's good. But, I have to re-write my code to incorporate the prepared statements in my sql.

Comment: See my edit. Try to read docs of the libraries you are using more thoroughly.

Comment: `def run_sql(sql)
 db = PG.connect(dbname: 'omdb')
 results = db.exec(sql)
 db.close 
 return results
end` I have this method I use to execute all my sql statements, right now it doesn't take any parameters. I have insert statements that take almost ten parameters. I understood your solution but I am not able to implement in my current design without changing lots of code.

Comment: Well, that's plainly bad design then. If you and your colleagues are OK with that, then leave it as is. :/

Comment: BTW, methods can receive more than one parameter, I hope you are aware.

Comment: Yeah I agree the design is not that great, I am going to refactor everything with ORM. It seems to handle all these problems. Thanks for your input anyway.